# Laravel 3D asset model viewer, model display is a whitescreen

Tags: php, laravel, 3d-model

I was wondering how to add a 3d model viewer in Laravel, I tried it but it only displays a white screen, the cursor is a Hand, and a "VR" button on the bottom right that once it is clicked, it will go to full screen but its pitch black. Let me know what code you want to see more.

Here is the blade PHP code:

[image: website image result once the Laravel app is started]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>3D Model Viewer</title>
    <style>
        /* Add any custom CSS styles for the viewer */
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #model-viewer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #model-viewer a-scene {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v6.0.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('fbx-model', {
            schema: {
                src: { type: 'string' }
            },
            init: function () {
                const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
                const object = this.el.object3D;
                const data = this.data;

                loader.load(data.src, function (fbx) {
                    object.add(fbx);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="model-viewer">
        <!-- The 3D model viewer will be rendered here -->
        <a-scene>
            <a-assets>
                <a-asset-item id="model" src="Table.fbx"></a-asset-item>
            </a-assets>

            <a-entity fbx-model="src: #model"></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```